# Error when rendering simple partial from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Ruby on Rails app I have the following partial `patients/_patient_link.html.erb`

```
<a class="patient" href="<%= patient_path(patient_link.id) %>">
  <span class="name"><%= patient_link.name %></span>
</a>
```

I'm trying to render this partial from the console using the following code:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
view = ActionView::Base.new('app/views/patients', {},  ActionController::Base.new)
output = view.render(file: '_patient_link.html', locals: {patient_link: User.last, current_user: User.last})
```

It returns me following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0..1)
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:150:in `url_for'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:280:in `call'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:223:in `call'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:345:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
    from /home/mateusz/projects/dashboard/app/views/patients/_patient_link.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_patients__patient_link_html_erb__1558238916296672676_82012840'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-4.2.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-4.2.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-4.2.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-4.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-4.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-4.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-4.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-4.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-4.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-4.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-4.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:46:in `render_template'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-4.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:27:in `render'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-4.2.8/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/haml-4.0.7/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:12:in `render_with_haml'
    from (irb):5
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

This href attribute inside partial is causing this error: `href="<%= patient_path(patient_link.id) %>"`. How can I fix that?

Comment: It's the same error as here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25007
So the suspicion is the error is somehow caused by one of gems you're using. Do you have any possibly non-compatible gems in your gemset?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but why are you creating the HTML in such a "manual" way? You can generate that HTML from **one line** of ruby code, with no need to hand-craft *any* HTML.

Comment: Just use [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), with a block.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with following code:

```
ApplicationController.new.render_to_string(
  :partial => 'patients/patient_link',
  :locals => { :patient_link => User.last , current_user: User.first}
)
```